# auto close a jquery lightbox window and redirect _parent page?

Tags: jquery, redirect

I'm trying to get a jquery lightbox window to auto close after a number of seconds and also redirect the parent page is this possible?

I'm new to php and jquery and am trying to find this answer on the net but am having no luck, please would someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as there are multiple jquery lightbox plugins I can't tell you what the exact solution would be. You might want to have a look at the standard javascript "setTimeout()" function to have a specific function called after a specific amount of milliseconds.
Also you would have to find out how you can close the specific lightbox plugin you're using.

As to redirecting to the parent page, wouldn't the parent page of a lightbox type of popup be the current page? If not: try storing the "parent page url" somewhere so that you can reach it when closing the lightbox.

Best of luck!